# CSV file from server URL not downloading

Tags: javascript

I'm messing with a piece of code to download a CSV from server. this is what I'm trying:

```
downloadCSVTemp(){
  let name =  'report.csv';

  const response =  api.getReportCSV()
    .then((res)=>{
      const blob = new Blob([res], { type: "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," });
      const blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const anchor = document.createElement("a");
      anchor.download = name;
      anchor.href = blobURL;
      anchor.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/csv", anchor.download, anchor.href].join(
        ":"
      );
      anchor.click();
    });
}

getReportCSV(){
    return axios.get("/export/assessments/");
  }
```

I intend to download a csv file from server url by an axios call, But this code is downloading an csv file which can't be opend by the browser & full of garbage data. What's the problem here ?

Comment: Your URL to download the file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `res` argument contains Axios [response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). When creating the blob, you should use `res.data`:

`new Blob([res.data], { type: "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," });`

Comment: its giving "undefined" in downloaded csv

Comment: @OsmanRafi I succefully tested exactly the same code with only a different (absolute) URL in the `getReportCSV()` function. So maybe this is also the problem. Do you have correct `baseURL` set in your axios config?